# Calculate Month Statistics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, group-by

I have a donations table where I'm trying to calculate the total amount for each month. For months without without any donations, I'd like the result to return 0.

Here's my current query:

```
Donation.calculate(:sum, :amount, :conditions => { 
  :created_at => (Time.now.prev_year.all_year) }, 
  :order => "EXTRACT(month FROM created_at)", 
  :group => ["EXTRACT(month FROM created_at)"])
```

which returns:

```
{7=>220392, 8=>334210, 9=>475188, 10=>323661, 11=>307689, 12=>439889}
```

Any ideas how to grab the empty months?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you'd left join to a calendar table (or [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) in PostgreSQL) to get the missing months but the easiest thing with Rails would be to merge your results into a Hash of zeroes; something like this:

```
class Donation
  def self.by_month
    h = Donation.calculate(:sum, :amount, :conditions => { 
      :created_at => (Time.now.prev_year.all_year) }, 
      :order => "EXTRACT(month FROM created_at)", 
      :group => ["EXTRACT(month FROM created_at)"])
    Hash[(1..12).map { |month| [ month, 0 ] }].merge(h)
  end
end
```

then just call the class method, `h = Donation.by_month`, to get your results.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to *mu is too short* answer, in Rails 3.2.12 did not work for me, ActiveRecord returns the keys as strings:

```
h = Donation.calculate(:sum, :amount, :conditions => { 
    :created_at => (Time.now.prev_year.all_year) }, 
    :order => "EXTRACT(month FROM created_at)", 
    :group => ["EXTRACT(month FROM created_at)"])
```

Which returns:

```
{"7"=>220392, "8"=>334210, "9"=>475188, "10"=>323661, "11"=>307689, "12"=>439889}
```

So when I merge the hash with zeros:

```
{1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>0, 10=>0, 11=>0, 12=>0, "7"=>220392, "8"=>334210, "9"=>475188, "10"=>323661, "11"=>307689, "12"=>439889}
```

The little fix (to_s):

```
Hash[(1..12).map { |month| [ month.to_s, 0 ] }].merge(h)
```